# How can I parallelize a for loop in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, networkx, python-multiprocessing

I wrote a function to analyze graphs in Python (uses NetworkX) and I need to run it 500 times, which takes a very long time. I tried parallelizing it using Pool from multiprocessing, but it crashed my computer, even when I set the range to a small value like 5 as opposed to 500. Can someone take a look at it? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import random as rn
import networkx as nx
import operator
import bcCalcs
from multiprocessing import Process

n1 = 100
n2 = 200
p = 1/2
q = 1/4000

percent = 0

def baInter():

    global percent
    icCount = .1*(n1+n2)
    while icCount >= (.1*(n1+n2)):

        ba = bcCalcs.baModel(n1, n2, 4, 4, q)

        g = nx.from_numpy_matrix(ba)

        globalBC = nx.betweenness_centrality(g, normalized = False)
        globalBCsorted = bcCalcs.sortBC(globalBC, 1)
        interCommNodes = bcCalcs.inter_comm_nodes(ba, n1)
        icCount = len(interCommNodes)


    for node in globalBCsorted:
        if node[0] in interCommNodes:
            percent = percent + 1

    print("x")        

if __name__ == "__main__":

    procs = []

    for i in range(500):
        proc = Process(target=baInter)
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join

percent = 100*(percent/500)

print(percent)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashed my computer" exactly? If your computer ran out of memory or overheated then you will likely need to modify your code rather than look for a different multiprocessing library.

Comment: @Kat It was using up 99% of the memory and it caused everything not to respond, which eventually made my computer run out of memory and overheat. I modified my code at least three times and it's still doing the same thing. I have no idea what's wrong with this code.

Comment: How much memory does it use when running with a single process? If it's already high usage with a single process, then using multiple won't help. It's hard to tell from the code you posted since it's not clear how large your arrays and return values are. Also, what is each process actually doing in parallel? All your processes seem to be running off the same global variables, i.e. doing the same thing.

Comment: @ahota It's using 86% memory on a single process and it takes about 2-3 seconds per iteration on 300 node graphs. And yes, I want them all to do the same thing. I'm investigating a conjecture and I want to run my code 500 times and obtain the percentage of that my conjecture is true.

Comment: @AlexLevine unfortunately if it's using that much memory in a single process, you won't be able to use a multiprocessing solution. The problem is that each process will have their own copy of the data, so even with two processes you're looking at ~160% memory usage. The only way to use multiple processes is if you can divide the amount of data that each process works on to keep the concurrent memory usage manageable.

Comment: @ahota I'm running this off of a cheap laptop, so obviously the memory usage isn't ideal. I was considering running it in Google cloud since I'll be able to use much more memory. Is my parallelization code correct at least (assuming I have sufficient memory)?

Comment: @AlexLevine it may be correct, but it's hard to tell what is ultimately being accomplished. My suggestion would be to run on a subset of the actual data if possible to test correctness with processes.

Comment: Also maybe worth considering a profiler, e.g. [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/), to help identify what structures consume so much memory.  (not totally sure how it interacts with multiprocessing but profiling 1 makes sense in any case)

Comment: Next to the memory problem, you create 500 processes (!). That takes a lot of time and creates quite an overhead that requires additional memory. I would suggest using less processes and a small queue to keep track of the number of iterations.